# Event listener not dispatched while testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I fire an event in my controller that dispatches a listener which sends an email. My code works fine in production. However I'm currently writing a testcase for it (using a full http request), but the event listener doesn't handle the fired event (which is fired).

How can I activate the listener in my testcase? Am I missing something? The code works well, when I test it by hand.

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7.1 and PHPUnit.
I have not used something like `Event::fake();`

Here is a minified version of my code:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $order = new Order($request->all());
        $order->store();

        event(new OrderStored($order));

        // no problem here

        return response()->json(['id' => $order->id()]);
    }
}
```

-

```
class OrderStored
{
    private $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        // this place is reachable
    }

    public function getOrder(): Order
    {
      return $this->order;
    }
}
```

-

```
class SendOrderStoredEmail
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        // this place is not reachable in my tests
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function handle(OrderStored $event): void
    {
        $this->mailer->send(new OrderStoredMail($event->getOrder()));
    }
}
```

And finally my EventServiceProvider:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends BaseEventServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        OrderStored::class => [SendOrderStoredEmail::class],
    ];
}
```

Comment: It seems to be, that `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer` is not instantiable during tests!

Comment: You should add the namespaces of all your classes you have listed, because it is unclear what they all are. I assume there is an event, a listener, a mailable, or maybe not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mail::fake();` injects an intance of MailFake into my listener, so the type hinting fails. Using the contract of `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer` solves the problem.